# Audio track from external storage file WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sd-card

Is it possible to create an AudioTrack object from an external storage file (SD card file)?
The problem at hand is getting the URI param for the audio track's constructor. I've tried feeding the path with both relative and absolute, but it song does not play.

Is there some I am missing? Can someone please provide a code example? The router map sample from MS is not useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set capability : ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE.Information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I know that. My problem is how to construct the URI, not how to see the SD card.